# android twitter outh tutorial callback problem

Tags: android, twitter

Trying the following tutorial

http://www.androidsdkforum.com/android-sdk-development/3-oauth-twitter.html

i am having trouble understanding callback URL

my twitter app name is "faisal-android" and my call back url i defined in code is

myapp://wozzon-android

and having entry in xml file as

```
           <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="faisal-android" />
            </intent-filter>
```

m i way to defining callback url is correct ??

when i run the code it gives me error "Authorization failed (server replied with a 401). This can happen if the consumer key was not correct or the signatures did not match"

my twitter app account settings as following
[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/a0c2689c73.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/a0c2689c73.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to check browser and not client if you use a callback url

I read something about this :
http://blog.sogeti.com/mobile/2010/03/twitter-oauth-for-android.html
(dead link)

Comment: This link is not working can anyone help me regarding the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Android – OAuth updates to Twitter**

http://dev.bostone.us/2009/07/16/android-oauth-twitter-updates/#awp::2009/07/16/android-oauth-twitter-updates/

Answer (score 0):

Check your callback UL in twitter . Enter any dummy URL not kept empty . 
You can write google.com, it work in my case.